# Flink 1.9.1 No FileSystem for scheme "file" error when submit jobs to cluster

Tags: apache-flink

we are recently upgrading our flink cluster to version 1.9.1. Error related to hadoop s3a occurs. The message is as below.

```
2020-01-16 08:39:49,283 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServerConnection            - PUT operation failed
org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "file"
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3332)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3403)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3371)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:477)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLocal(FileSystem.java:433)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:301)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:378)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:456)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:200)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createTmpFileForWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:572)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ADataBlocks$DiskBlockFactory.create(S3ADataBlocks.java:811)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.createBlockIfNeeded(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:190)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.<init>(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:168)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:778)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1169)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1149)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1038)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.hadoop.HadoopFileSystem.create(HadoopFileSystem.java:141)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.hadoop.HadoopFileSystem.create(HadoopFileSystem.java:37)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.FileSystemBlobStore.put(FileSystemBlobStore.java:73)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.FileSystemBlobStore.put(FileSystemBlobStore.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobUtils.moveTempFileToStore(BlobUtils.java:444)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer.moveTempFileToStore(BlobServer.java:694)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServerConnection.put(BlobServerConnection.java:351)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServerConnection.run(BlobServerConnection.java:114)
```

I guess the s3 hadoop filesystem is trying to create local files but it cannot find 'file' filesystem. Can anyone advise the potential problem here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the s3 filesystem with the plugin mechanism?

Comment: yes, sir. We copied Flink Hadoop s3 jar to plugin directories

Answer (score 1):

The plugin loader had a [shortcoming](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14574) in 1.9.0 and 1.9.1 that prevented the plugins from lazily loading new classes. It's fixed in the upcoming 1.9.2 and 1.10 releases.

For the time being, you could simply add the jar to the lib folder as a workaround. Note, however, that in 1.10 you can only use s3 through plugins, so keep that in mind when you would upgrade.